# Nativescript send camera capture to server

Tags: nativescript

In my Nativescript application I would like to capture an image using the camera module and then send the bytes directly to the server via http call.

Here is my code (incomplete for brevity):

```js
var cameraModule = require("camera");
var http = require("http");
...

cameraModule.takePicture().then(function (img) {
  // how to extract the actual bytes from img???
  
  http.request({
    url: some_url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
    content: ???
  });
});
```

Is there a way to do that?

I was looking at nativescript-background-http and it seems to fit my requirements exactly, but the example shows the file being loaded from a path only.  I did not have any luck making this to work on iOS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A couple things;

1. "img" is actually a image source.
2. At this point the built in HTTP module does not support direct binary transfers, so we need to convert it to something that can be sent over the wire.  So base64 is a text representation that can support binary, and it is a common encoding/decoding method.
3. Since we already have it as a image source we just use the cool toBase64String ability which give us the Base 64 data.

So here is basically is how I would do it (tested under android).

```
var cameraModule = require('camera');

var some_url="http://somesite";
// img is a image source
cameraModule.takePicture().then(function (img) {
  // You can use "jpeg" or "png".   Apparently "png" doesn't work in some
  // cases on iOS.  
  var imageData = img.toBase64String("jpeg");

  http.request({
    url: some_url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/base64" },
    content: imageData
  }).then(function() { 
    console.log("Woo Hoo, we sent our image up to the server!");
  }).catch(function(e) { 
    console.log("Uh oh, something went wrong", e);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael,  This is the approach I was looking for, but when I run the code, iSource.fromFile(img) returns null.  Is there something else I am missing.

Comment: after some further research, it turns out that the img is already an ImageSource object.  However, calling .toBase64String() still returns null. Very strange.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong initially, I could have sworn the docs said it was a file name.  :)    Img is actually a image source, not a file name.   So the revised code I have actually tested on a Android 4.4 emulator and console logged the imageData and it had a base 64 string.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I wonder if there is a problem with the iOS implementation?  I am getting a null when I execute the same code.  I created an issue (https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2353) Hopefully someone from the NativeScript team will clarify the issue.

Comment: Ok, I got some clarification from NickIliev from NativeScript. The proper syntax is img.toBase64String("png"); or img.toBase64String("jpeg");
After correcting this line, everything worked.

Comment: BE CAREFULL! Be mindful of image format conversion - I selected a jpeg image and running `toBase64String("png")` on it made my phone go fully unresponsive and in lockdown mode. Selecting a png and running `toBase64String("jpeg")` had no problems though.

Comment: That is why I have that note in my example; I have heard of several reasons where 'png' doesn't work.   Using 'jpeg' is the safest and best option.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. If your backend can take a base64 string you can use the image-source class and manipulate the data. I'm on my phone or I'd mock up a sample. It really depends what you expect on the server to be honest but most options are possible with NativeScript using the image-source and ui/image component.

http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource.html#tobase64string

Going from memory here but try this when you get the (IMG) back.

`var data = img.tobase64string();` that should give you a base 64 string of the image.

Just found this awesome sample from another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815237/1893557
This will work to send the file after you save it locally and uses the background-http plugin.

Comment: Thanks @brad-martin, I looked at that link, but the background http expects the url to the file to submit.  I am not sure how to get this from the img variable returned from the camera module