# Nativescript upload image

Tags: image, file-upload, image-uploading, nativescript

Hi I would like to take a picture and upload it to my server. Here is my nativescript code below
[image]

And here is the code for the request I am accessing to upload the image
[image]

Once I run my app and take picture to send it to the server. The server returns an error message just like this
[image]

Note: This is the headers I used for the nativescript app

```
var headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
```

Also in nativescript is there a method createReadStream() for the file-system module?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932936/nativescript-send-camera-capture-to-server

Comment: Hey @Nathanael tried your method but it seems that the server is throwing an error stating that application/base64 is a bad content-type also console.log(files.avatar) is still throwing undefined :(

Comment: On the server side you need to un-base64 it.  The image is transfered as a base64 text file, with my method.

Comment: @Nathanael BTW I used formidable library for the server, https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Comment: If you are wanting to use  "Form" data; then you need to use the latest version of nativescript-background-http as I recently added the ability to upload a form value to that code base.  And Aaron's code below should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nativescript-background-http` plugin.
Here is how you use it

```
var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");

// save the image somewhere
var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var pathOfImage = fs.path.join(folder.path, "Test.png");
var saved = image.saveToFile(pathOfImage,".png");
var request = 
        url : uploadPhotoUrl,
        method : "POST",
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"
        }
    };
var task = session.uploadFile(pathOfImage,request);
```

**EDIT**

On backend ( nodejs + express ) you can implement middleware function and use that :

```
var rawParser = bodyParser.raw({
    type: 'application/octet-stream', extended: true
});

app.post("/photoUpload",rawParser,function(req,res){
var path = "uploads/test.jpg";
var file = fs.writeFileSync(path,req.body);
});
```

Comment: Tried nativescript-background-http it still doesn't work server is still throwing undefined :(

Comment: How do you get the path to the image using the Camera module?

Comment: can you clarify some things?
path is defined but never used. what is it used for?
the nativescript uploader code is executing a POST method, but the express code is a GET method. when is the express GET route called?

Comment: @zero upadted the answer :)

Comment: @RaymondCamden you could use a plugin like nativescript-mediafilepicker that returns the file paths

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of file upload to QuickBlox (which uses AWS S3 under the hood with “multipart/form-data” supported)

```
    var fs = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
    var imagepicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
    var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
    var parseUri = require("parseUri");


    var ile = fs.File.fromPath(this.filePath);
    var size = file.readSync().length;
    var contentType = 'image/jpeg';

    var uri = parseUri(createResult.blob_object_access.params),
       uploadUrl = uri.protocol + "://" + uri.authority + uri.path;

    var uploadParams = [];
    Object.keys(uri.queryKey).forEach(function(val) {
       uploadParams.push({name: val, value: decodeURIComponent(uri.queryKey[val])});
    });
    uploadParams.push({name: "file", filename: self.filePath, mimeType: contentType}); // If the element is named anything other than 'file', you're likely to receive a MaxPostPreDataLengthExceededError response when upload to S3.

    var request = {
        url: uploadUrl,
        method: "POST"
    };

    var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
    var task = session.multipartUpload(uploadParams, request);

    function onEvent(e) {
        console.log("event: " + e.eventName);
        if(e.object.description){
          console.log(e.object.description);
        }
        if(e.error){
          console.log(e.error);
        }
        if(e.currentBytes){
          console.log(e.currentBytes + " of " + e.totalBytes);
        }
        if(e.data){
          console.log(e.data);
        }
    }

    task.on("progress", onEvent.bind(this));
    task.on("error", onEvent.bind(this));
    task.on("responded", onEvent.bind(this));
    task.on("complete", onEvent.bind(this));
});
```

Full code on gist https://gist.github.com/soulfly/b55d6c0dd9448bc1dc1133793a6ac22d